# close bootstrap offcanvas by button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, canvas

i use the bootstrap 3 offcanvas to make a filter option for a table visible.

everything works fine but the only problem is that you cannot close the sidebar by clicking on the menu button again. if you click everywhere else the sidebar disapears but not on the button.

what could we do? i've tried to put the grey mask over the all with z-index but it doesn't work. i think it would work if we can disable the button while the sidebar is open. or change the link on the button if the sidebar is open.

thanks for your support or/and hints!

here you can see my problem:
[www.retrofocus.ch/matrix/offcanvas](http://www.retrofocus.ch/matrix/offcanvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we fixed it pretty simple. we made a div with a higher z-index than the button and putted an opacity to that plus made a margin-left of 20%. now if the sidebar is closed you can click the button. if the sidebar is open, the div with the opacity cover the button and you cannot click it anymore. if you click on the button again the st-pusher of the bootstrap canvas will automaticly bring you back to the content on the right and close the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you have to ass jquery click event as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  .............
  .............
  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
     if($('#st-container').hasClass('st-menu-open')){
       $('#st-container').removeClass('st-menu-open');
     }
  });
  .............
  .............
});
```

In above jQuery Click function will work.

Comment: hmm, i've added this but it's not working :( you can see now this script in the head area.

Comment: i think the problem is that other js commands overwirte this. but we've fixed it. see above. thanks